# Simple synthesis of thiocyanates

Tags: synthesis

Can sodium thiocyanate be synthesised by combining equimolar amounts of ammonia, sodium hydrosulfide and carbon dioxide in the presence of phosphorous pentoxide by the following reaction: NH3 + NaSH + CO2 -> NaSCN + 2H2O ?

Answer (score 1):

> It has been observed spectroscopically but has not been isolated as a pure substance.

[Thiocyanic_acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiocyanic_acid)

Regarding the sodium salt,  creating it in concentrated sulphuric acid cannot be considered seriously.

$\ce{P4O10}$ would not be much better, forming various forms of condensated phosphoric acid.

Furthermore, carbon dioxide manifests  weak oxidative properties at very high temperatures only.

Comment: I see. Edited question.